# Docker daemon restart and reattaching to containers

Tags: docker, centos, docker-compose

If I kill my docker daemon process and then restart it, any containers that were running are now listed with *Exited* status and cannot be restarted using docker-compose as it will complain about the container name already being in use.

Docker containers can be started again using docker start  but this could be hard when you've many containers.

Is there any way to restart the docker daemon, leave containers running (so as to not disrupt traffic) and have the daemon reattach to the containers?

uname -a:

```
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 19 22:10:57 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

docker info:

```
Containers: 23
 Running: 2
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 21
Images: 16
Server Version: 1.11.1
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-253:0-1567975-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Base Device Size: 10.74 GB
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 3.738 GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 28 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 7.688 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.14 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 WARNING: Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. Either use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` or use `--storage-opt dm.no_warn_on_loop_devices=true` to suppress this warning.
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.107-RHEL7 (2015-10-14)
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: null host bridge
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 7.64 GiB
Name: 
ID: 
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug mode (client): false
Debug mode (server): false
Username: 
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is something that will be addressed in 1.12:

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2658