# Docker Containers Running When Daemon is Down

Tags: docker

I found this article [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37394745/docker-daemon-restart-and-reattaching-to-containers) and i understand that when the daemon is down the containers are down as well and setting can be made to restart them when daemon is restarted. In [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/live-restore/) i found that as of 1.2 version when the daemon is down the container will keep running.

My confusion(per my understanding) is that daemon is the server/interface that lets containers to communicate with the host OS. How will the containers communicate with the host OS during daemon downtime.